# DirSelectBox in Python >3.5?

Tags: python, tkinter, deprecation-warning

`tkinter.tix` has been deprecated since Python 3.6, and the warning it emits *implies* that we'll be able to access its elements from `tkinter.ttk`:

> DeprecationWarning: The Tix Tk extension is unmaintained, and the `tkinter.tix` wrapper module is deprecated in favor of `tkinter.ttk`

However, I can't see where we're supposed to get [`DirSelectBox`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.tix.html#tkinter.tix.DirSelectBox) from:

```py
Python 3.11.4 (tags/v3.11.4:d2340ef, Jun  7 2023, 05:45:37) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> from tkinter.tix import DirSelectBox

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1
DeprecationWarning: The Tix Tk extension is unmaintained, and the tkinter.tix wrapper module is deprecated in favor of tkinter.ttk
>>> from tkinter import DirSelectBox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from tkinter import DirSelectBox
ImportError: cannot import name 'DirSelectBox' from 'tkinter' (C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py)
>>> from tkinter import DirSelectBox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    from tkinter import DirSelectBox
ImportError: cannot import name 'DirSelectBox' from 'tkinter' (C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py)
```

Since `tix` has been deprecated, and `ttk` doesn't contain the widget, nor does `tkinter`, where are we supposed to get it from nowadays?

Comment: That message is saying that `ttk` is *a better choice moving forward*, not that it's an exact drop-in replacement for `tix`.  Is there some reason you can't use the standard `tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory()`?